# WordPress permalink prefix

Tags: permalinks

I have a small e-commerce site in WordPress and I am having some difficulties in getting the right permalink structure.

Basically, for basic pages it should look like: `domainname.com/page_title`

Other post types should have the structure: `domainname.com/post_type_slug/item_title`

Everything is fine except for the blog posts. I want it to look like: `domainname.com/blog/post_title`

Having the permalink setting as `%postname%`, I get `domainname/post_title`. On the other hand, `/%category%/%postname%` returns `domainname.com/category/post_title`. Obviously, entering `/blog/%postname%` won't work either because that would affect the permalinks of other post types.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't specify if you're using regular WordPress pages/posts or if you're using a plugin such as WP e-commerce or WooCommerce. Can you clarify this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `/blog/%postname%` is the correct setting for permalinks in this case. The `/blog/` portion of the permalink will only be added to custom post types if they have been registered using the `rewrite => with_front` parameter set to `true`.